# Filter project search via tags on SonarQube API

Tags: sonarqube, dashboard

On our site we use SonarQube 6.4 to analyze over 150 projects by different teams. While some projects are actually just branches (only differ in version) most of our team projects have a different name. To filter the relevant ones for our team we added tags to the projects, which works fine in the project view (`/projects?tags=mytag`). However neither the project view list, nor the visualization is for us any useful as a full-screen dashboard (e.g. no checkerboard).

As SonarQube discontinued the dashboard we tried to setup our own by using the provided API, but unfortunately a call to `/api/components/search?qualifiers=TRK` will just return too many entries and the parameter `q` for the component name is too restrictive. Unless I missed it, looking at the API description `/api/webservices/list` it seems it is possible to query for tags on e.g. issues but not on components (neither on SonarQube 6.7 as far as I could tell).

Is there any *other* convenient way to filter projects by a development team or are there known plans to add the tags filter as well on the component/project search?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

PS: I did try to search here e.g. via '[sonarqube] api tag' but the posts I found where more related to maintain tags but not how to filter on them via the API.

Comment: Tangentially to your question, I'm curious by what you mean here: "neither the project view list, nor the visualization is for us any useful as a full-screen dashboard (e.g. no checkerboard)" because the graphs in the Projects page do include a background grid.

Comment: I meant specifically for the purpose of a dashboard to see the state of a build across the room, a checker board or red, yellow green bar lines on black background are a better indicator. Sure the developer may get a warning in his IDE or via mail but what if it is actually due to a merge that happened outside or if the colleague went to lunch? In short the current GUI is good for an in depth view of details but not as much for a warning board for failing quality gates for which we will use the Atlasboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a specific parameter for this. Instead, you'll use the `filter` parameter, like so: `&filter=tags%20%3D%20your-tag-name`

BTW I figured this out by running a tag-specific search on the projects page and using my browser's developer tools to see the requested URL. In general, if the UI gives you a way to pull or narrow a data set then it's supported by the web services ('cause that's where the UI gets its data).

Comment: Thanks a lot! As a note I tried adding the parameter with `/api/components/search?qualifiers=TRK&filter=tags%20%3D%20your-tag-name` which does not work! However as suggested I inspected what the GUI is doing, which actually use the undocumented API endpoint  `/api/components/search_projects` which indeed accept the parameter `filter'. As of now I will use that undocumented feature in hope it won't change anytime soon, but I hope it will find one way its way into the public documented API.

Comment: Hi Ann, 
Has anything changed from the time of this post? 
We have exactly the same requirement, but cannot use the APIs for security issues.
We are using Version 6.7.6 (build 38781) , and want to be able to use the "project" tags in the "Issues" screen, thus getting look over only the Issues that came from Projects that we manually tagged.

Comment: This answer helped me along the way. I find the guide for the SonarQube as 'utter shaite' since the examples are not helpful and are confusing at times.

What I'm trying to do:
api/components/search_projects?filter=tags=<myTag>&ps=500

Which seems to be possible to do according to the web api guide